# array.unshift invoked using apply() causes "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript

This code:

```
var arr = [];
arr.unshift.apply(arr, new Array(200000));
```

causes: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded 
(see  http://jsfiddle.net/BnLxf/1/)

While this code works fine:

```
var arr = [];
arr.unshift(new Array(200000));
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Which browser are you using? It has a badly coded JavaScript engine. Works fine in Opera

Comment: These two codes are not equivalent. You are looking for `.call` instead of `.apply`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now why they are not equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first example is equivalent to this:

```
 arr.unshift(undefined, undefined, undefined, /* undefined 199,997 more times */);
```

Your second example just passes `unshift` **one** argument, which is an array with no entries and a `length` of `200000`.

This is because the purpose of `Function#apply` is to call a function with a given `this` value of arguments which are then then passed onto the target function as discrete (individual) arguments.

It's not entirely surprising that a JavaScript engine chokes when asked to call a function with 200,000 discrete arguments. (I also wouldn't have been surprised if it worked.)

If you want to pass the array as just a single argument, but you want to use something `apply`-like, use `call`:

```
arr.unshift.call(arr, new Array(200000));
```

`call` passes on the arguments you give it exactly as you give it to them (except the first one, which is what to use as `this` during the call).

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why anyone would take the first approach to copy an array into another (imagine a valid array instead of new Array(20000))? I extracted this code from a JavaScript library (ExtJs)  so whoever wrote had something in mind.

Comment: @SergiuB: JavaScript arrays are missing a fairly obvious feature: `append`. As in, `a.append(b)` to take all of the contents of `b` and add them to the end of `a`. There's `a.concat(b)`, but it creates a *new* array containing the contents of `a` followed by the contents of `b`. So although I've never seen it with `unshift`, I've seen ([and written about](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/05/appending-to-array.html)) using `a.push.apply(a, b)` to do this. I've never tried it with a huge array, but for "reasonable" numbers of elements it works just fine.

Comment: I understand the technique now, cool. I ended up splitting the unshift.apply call with the huge array argument into several smaller calls to avoid the call stack exceeded error.

Answer (score 0):

The `Function#apply` method expects an array as 2nd parameter. You should embrace `new Array(200000)` with brackets:

```
var arr = [];
arr.unshift.apply(arr, [new Array(200000)]);
```

As Chris said, you can also call method `.call` instead of `.apply`:

```
var arr = [];
arr.unshift.call(arr, new Array(200000));
```

Comment: Or just use `call` instead of `apply`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now the difference. What I really wanted to know is why arr.unshift.apply(arr, new Array(200000)) throws the error, and  T.J.'s answer clarified it.